# Limit question as x approaches -infinity (Absolute value in limit)

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm given this limit question which I don't know how to do.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty }(\frac{2x+\left | x \right |}{4x-3\left | x \right |}) $$. Can someone give me some hints? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: What is $|x|$ for $x < 0$ ?

Comment: assume $x < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Your limit is simply

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x-x}{4x+3x}$$

Comment: How to simplify?

Comment: @Mathxx By definition, $$|x|=\begin{cases}\;\;\;x&,\;\;x\ge 0\\{}\\-x&,\;\;x<0\end{cases}$$